# Opencart employee access to order status and hide delete button

Tags: php, opencart

I want to give my employee access to change the status and add history, but not able to edit the order or delete them. Currently if I give access to modify order they can delete the order, edit address or products, if I disable their access to modify order they cannot even change the status of the order and add history.

Any plugin out there for it? Also I don't want them to see the delete button and some how not be able to use it.

Comment: Would you show us what you have tried? I imagine a good session of search engine searching might turn something up. If you are asking for plugins, it's worth knowing that requests for tutorial/plugin/library/tech recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, as traditionally these sorts of questions have attracted spam answers.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what version you're using but on 1.5.6.x you'd want to disable their permission to modify orders and then look in **admin/controller/sale/order.php** for this line around line 2165:

```
$this->data['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
```

and comment it out like this:

```
//$this->data['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
```

This basically overrides the permissions check when updating status or adding history while viewing an order.